# Increased Ram Usage on android device

Tags: android

I run the following code to start a service:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreatingService.class);
        startService(intent);
        //finish();   
    }
}
```

This initially takes 13-14 MB of memory when seen in the task manager. When i go back to home screen and kill the activity (swiping off from recent list) the service gets recreated(`START_STICKY`) and it takes around 3-4 MB of memory from then on. Also if the `finish()` was not commented off in the above code it would take 3-4 MB again. But I cannot do this.

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening and a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't finish your activity, it stays in your memory, say in the background.

Why is this any good?

Because the activity does not need to be recrated and there by loads a lot faster.

Should you worry about this?

No, Android will terminate your app on it's own if it's running low on resources.